# how do i search trhough array of objects in firestore to fin the smallest value

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of documents which looks like so:

```
  name: string;
  address: IAddress;
  tests: Item[];
  rating?: number;
  photo?: string;
```

every document has a name as ID and inside every document there is an array of Item and Item is an object of shape:

```
export type Item = {
  title: string;
  price: number;
};
```

Now I have a separate collection i which there is a field of min and max price for the Item, and I need to search the abovementioned collection and the array of object inside to find what min and max price of item. How should I do that? I was trying like so

```
    const q = query(
      collection(firestore, "stores"),
      where("item.title", "==", this.title),
      orderBy("item.price")
    );
```

And I just realized that this is not just item.title, but this is an array, so it would be item[x].title. How can I search for it in the array?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to search across a collection of documents for the one with the lowest price in an array.

You'll want to add a field to the document that captures the lowest price from the array (say `item.lowestprice`) and then use *that* in the query:

```
const q = query(
  collection(firestore, "stores"),
  where("item.title", "==", this.title),
  orderBy("item.lowestprice"), // 
  limit(1) // 
);
```

Comment: Hi @Frank van Puffelen, thanks for help today and yesterday as well :) How do I capture the lowest price in the array to the field in the document? Thanks

Comment: There's nothing magic there: whenever you add a price to the document (which you by definition do on an individual document) check if it's lower than all existing prices, and if so set that value in `item.lowestprice`.